# Extent not working for imagemagick6 mogrify

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

Linux Mint comes with **imagemagick 6** ( Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 ) and I'm using **mogrify** to edit some pictures.

I have a bunch of pictures that are 700*1000 and I need to add whitespace to either end to make them 768x1000 so I use this command

```
mogrify *.jpg -gravity center -extent 768x1000
```

But the pic stays 700x1000, try the same with convert on a single picture and this works fine. Does *extent* not work with **mogrify**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the web I found the Imagemagick [mogrify](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) page and it says extent is supported in version 7.

Looking at the examples on the page I would try

```
mogrify gravity center -extent 768x1000 *.jpg
```

You should also add more details to the version number as version 6 covered a lot of years and had a lot of releases. Also extent may not have always been supported in V6 mogrify.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that is it. The file selector should be at the end.